# PIC flights during grace period

Tags: faa-regulations

If my base month for recurrent 135 checks is June and I fly as PIC in July and subsequently don't complete required testing in July, can I be violated for any July flights?

Comment: Does [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1601/62) help?